# A part of styles didnt work when i add <!DOCTYPE html>

Tags: html, css

The style of y "Tweet" button disappears whem i adding !DOCTYPE html.

[Tweet with style](https://i.stack.imgur.com/30cP8.jpg)

[Style gone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V2Qgi.jpg)

[Css part](https://i.stack.imgur.com/08l2C.jpg)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Buttons</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/buttons.css">
    </head>
    <body>    
        <button class="buttonYT">SUBSCRIBE</button>
        <button class="JOIN">JOIN</button>
        <button class="Tweetb">Tweet</button>
    </body>

</html>
```

css part of Tweet button from button.css

```
.tweetb {
    background-color: rgb(29, 155, 240);
    color: white;
    border: none;
    height: 36px;
    width: 74px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 15px;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-left: 8px;
    transition: box-shadow 0.15s;
    vertical-align: top;
}

.tweetb:hover {
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}
```

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) -- [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)  --  Please do **not** include images of code ..  We cannot reproduce your problem with images!  --  Also the problem just appears to be a typo in your class name  `Tweetb`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your screenshot, the class name for the tweet button is `TweetBT`, whereas in your `button.css` it's `.tweetBT`, which should be `.TweetBT`.
As the class name is not matching, the CSS is not applied. It's not an issue with !DOCType Html.